# Unicode and jQuery Virtual Keyboad

Tags: jquery, virtual, keyboard-events

I am using jQuery virtual keyboard plug-in for developing a virtual keyboard which consists of Unicode values using customLayout.

```
$('#unicodeInput') .keyboard({
    layout: 'custom',
    customLayout: {
        'default' :  [
                                     ....................
                                     ....................
        ]
    }
}) .addTyping();
```

When I press the button on virtual keyboard the Unicode value is getting inserted fine in the textarea. When I press the keyboard english characters are getting inserted.

It seems I need to add some additional functionalities so that the associated unicode with the key on keyboard will be inserted. When I press a key I want to insert the Unicode value instead of English characters into the textarea. What are the additional things which I need to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use this reference.
According to site you are required to use the HEX value of the characters in Unicode
Check it
http://blog.seanja.com/2010/03/jquery-contains-selector-and-unicode-characters/